# How to create Saas with plans priced by server resource usage?

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, saas

If I create a multi-tenant system using Laravel, what kind of software/tool do I need to use to be able to impose limitations on the use of server resources (cpu, memory, bandwidth) according to the plan that the customer hires?

What I'm looking for is something similar to how Shopify works.  My goal with this question is to find a solution that works for this purpose at the lowest possible cost, at least to start the project and see the results.

The choice of this pricing method is precisely to keep the initial costs low, because it can happen that one or more clients have websites with a large number of visits and end up consuming all the server's resources causing slowdowns on the other clients' websites.

Anyone who has a saas in this model, or has worked for a company like this, can help me understand how it works and give me a starting point or suggestion on how to do it.

Comment: What's the more specific use case? You could roll each tenant on a separate VPS/computer instance that has limited resources, and if the tenant upgrades you'll have to reconfigure each "server", you'll need to automatize all that probably

Comment: @AlexandruTrandafirCatalin I put more details, see if it is now easier to understand.

Comment: Have you started capturing the CPU like metrics that are being used by the tenant's.  This way we can setup filters to short circuit requests that have crossed the threshold metric. This can be used for any metric (Hardware / Software)

Comment: @Saravanan I haven't created the project yet, for now it's just planning.

Comment: If you plan to allocate the resources to do fine grained metric capture, it is a great asset to monitoring and charging the customers by plans, the more detailed we give metrics, the more interested customers are ....